# PolyUtil Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the class PolyUtil from Google Map Utility. But when I am adding dependency in gradle.build it is showing sync error.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

What can be the possible reason?

total gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shaby.supportindia.myapplicationmap"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is that all your dependencies in Gradle file? In that range, I can't see any error. Also, what is your `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: I updated the question with complete gradle.